# How can i make server go to a specific folder when a specific URL hits the servers?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, webserver, server-side

I have a wordpress blog and i am a web developer.

The thing is i want to display demo web projects when ever some one hits `/demo` from there.

What i exactly want is, only when someone hits `/demo` URL rather then redirecting to index file as default wordpress does i want server to look into `demo` folder and from there anything after `demo` in the url like `project1` in this URL `/demo/project1` move to that project1 folder.

So what script do i need to put in .htaccess to achieve this ?

Comment: Search about `enable directory browsing`. It may help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess redirect to achieve this purpose, do:

```
Redirect 301 "/demo" "http://www.example.com/demo"
```

Or you could add the following to your wordpress config.

```
/* Redirect example.com to example.com/demo using wordpress config */
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com/demo');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com/demo');
```

Hope it helps.